# .text() removes all input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have form that users fill out a set of checkmarks and when they click a button, the output is a sequence of notes.  In this form, a div in my HTML is set up to pull a list of items which will appear in an email.  Sometimes, the user needs to fill out an empty text box for one of the items.  However, the way the code is written currently, I can get the text for items on the page, but it removes all the text inside the text boxes.  Is there a way to include the text boxes too?  Here is the code sample:

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="DocsNeeded"> This <input class="DocsNeeded" checked="checked" type="text" size="20" /> information is an example of an item with an input field<br><br> 
    </p>
</div>
<div>  
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="DocsNeeded"> This is <input type="text" size="20" /> another example of an item with an input field<br><br>
    </p>    
</div>
```

JavaScript Function

```
$(".DocsNeeded:checked:visible").each(function() {      
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        docs += "• " + $(this).parent("p").text().trim() + "\r\n";
    }
});
```

**EDIT**  Based on the questions below:

Essentially the output text (what I'm hoping to get from this question) that the user will then copy and paste into a pre-formatted email will be:

> Mr. Person
>
> Here is a list of all the documents that you did not send us
>
> • This [user input here] information is an example of an item with an input field
>
> • This is [user input here] another example of an item with an input field

Comment: I'd suggest reading the documentation of jQuery.text(). "The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method."

Comment: you are using the `.text()` only .So text will come.`.val()` is used to get the value from input type

Comment: That code wouldn't remove anything by itself. What is `docs` and what are you doing with it? And what are you trying to do? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to end each paragraph with 2 line-breaks. You probably don't need to put each paragraph inside a div, either.

Comment: I updated the original question from above so that it's more clear.  Thanks for the guidance charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) sets/gets the "text" inside an HTML element. It is not the input type="text". Example close to what you achieve is below. I also included a sample usage of text().

Also, jQuery way of accessing an element's children is to use [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) or [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) (deeper).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickme').click( function() {
    var docs = '';
    $(".DocsNeeded:checked:visible").each(function() {      
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            docs += "• " + 
              $(this).parent("p").find('.label-1').text() + ' ' + 
              $(this).parent("p").find('input[type=text]').val() + ' ' + 
              $(this).parent("p").find('.label-2').text() + "\r\n";
        }
    });
    $('#result').text(docs);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="DocsNeeded"> <span class="label-1">This</span> <input class="DocsNeeded" checked="checked" type="text" size="20" /> <span class="label-2">information is an example of an item with an input field</span><br><br> 
    </p>
</div>
<div>  
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="DocsNeeded"> <span class="label-1">This is</span> <input type="text" size="20" /> <span class="label-2">another example of an item with an input field</span><br><br>
    </p>    
</div>

<button id="clickme">Click Me </button>
<hr />
<div id="result" style="white-space:pre"></div>
<hr />
```

Comment: Well, this shows me how to isolate the inputs.  What I'm trying to obtain is the full statement with the inputs within the statement.

Comment: That is possible. (See the modified example above). But I don't think it's the correct approach since those texts are static. Just build your mail template string by filling it with the dynamic info gathered from the input fields.

Comment: I know that this is a clunky way of doing this.  However, as you can see I'm pretty new.  I found something in my predecessor's code that I can use later, but that'll take me some time to adapt and the client has a quick turnaround time on this project.  So I really appreciate your help.